# How to get gitlab username based on gitlab user id

Tags: gitlab, pipeline

For a project I am running a pipeline that provisions servers and configures them. In the server configuration, the gitlab username needs to be added. I need the username specifically, as this is not based on either gitlab user id or user mail (so I cannot just use the gitlab_user_email variable and derive the username from there).

Is there any way to fetch the user's username via their gitlab user id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can get user details including `username` from api endpoint [for user](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/users.html#for-user)

```sh
GET /users/:id

#curl example for gitlab.com
curl "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/users/<user id>?access_token=<your gitlab token>"
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I managed to completely forget about the API!